# Python - How to filter a list by the content of its elements?

Tags: python, list

I  made a function which filters my list and it looks like

```
def listDirs(directory):
        listD = [d for d in [os.path.join(myPath, d1) for d1 in os.listdir(directory)] if os.path.isdir(d)]
        sortListD = np.unique(np.array([i[-10:] for i in listD]))
        if[ np.array([i.split("-")[1] for i in sortListD]) != "2017" ]: # <- here
                sortListD.remove(i)
        return sortListD
```

As you imagine, the line marked does not work and I'm not really comfortable with the usage of python loops.

What i want to do is to verify that my `i` element in my `sortListD` is formatted as `'YYYY-MM-DD'`, and remove it if not.

my `sortListD` looks like this:

```
['2015-06-18' '2015-07-20' '2015-08-05' '2015-09-01' '2015-10-10'
 '2016-01-04' '2016-01-06' '2016-01-11' '2016-01-18' '2016-01-20'
 '2016-02-15' '2016-02-25' '2016-04-16' '2016-05-03' '2016-06-07'
 '2016-06-21' '2016-06-22' '2016-06-24' '2016-07-30' '2016-08-02'
 '2016-08-23' '2016-09-07' '2016-09-15' '2016-09-19' '2016-09-28'
 '2016-09-30' '2016-10-03' '2016-10-06' '2016-10-10' '2016-10-17'
 '2016-11-07' '2016-11-11' '2016-11-14' '2016-11-18' '2016-11-23'
 '2016-11-27' '2016-12-08' '2016-12-12' '2016-12-20' '2017-01-03'
 '2017-01-06' '2017-02-02' '2017-02-03' '2017-02-20' '2017-04-20'
 '2017-05-08' '2017-05-22' '2017-06-01' '2017-09-23' '2017-11-16'
 '2017-11-23' '2017-11-30' '**ata_Q1/old**' '**uonic_data**']
```

The elements in bold are the one i want to remove.

Comment: You are not sorting, you are *filtering*.

Comment: Consider adding the tag [tag:numpy]? Also is this [tag:python-2.7] or [tag:python-3.x]?

Comment: So the output should just be a list again?

Comment: Yup filtering* sorry

Comment: And yeah i want to have a list again, so i can get my YYYY-MM-DD elements separatly

Comment: why specifically the test for `i.split("-")[1]` being not equal to 2017? Your correct strings all *start* with 2017, that test would match strings that have 2017 in the second position.

Comment: Also, why the `[-10:]` slice? Did you just want to test the directory names and produce a list of those (as the function name implies)? Can you give a short sample of names in a directory (can be made up) and the expected return value of the function please. Include some data that would make it clear why a unique set is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just wanted a sequence of unique date strings, use a set comprehension to extract the unique last 10 characters of each directory name, and then see if each string starts with `2017`:

```
def listDirs(directory):
    # a set of the last 10 characters of all directory names in `directory`
    paths = {p[-10:] for p in os.listdir(directory)
             if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(directory, f))}
    # a list of all those unique substrings that start with 2017-
    return [p for p in paths if p.startswith('2017-')]
```

This uses two [*comprehensions*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), loops that produce a Python container object directly. The first, `{....}` produces a set (where all contained elements are unique), and the second produces a list. The `if ...` parts filter the loop to limit what is included.

The above returns just those 10-character long tails of the directory names. If you wanted the *whole* directory name, then there is no need to use a set (names in a directory are already guaranteed to be unique) and you only need to slice in the list comprehension filter. We can make the directory test loop a generator expression to avoid creating an intermediary list:

```
def listDirs(directory):
    # a set of the last 10 characters of all directory names in `directory`
    dirs = (p in os.listdir(directory)
            if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(directory, f))}
    return [d for d in dirs if d[-10:].startswith('2017-')]
```

The `startswith` test is pretty simplistic, and there can easily be false positives. You may want to test for any valid date string of the form YYYY-MM-DD, including testing that the date actually exists. That's easiest done by having the `datetime` library try and parse the string; if this fails, you know you don't have a valid date:

```
from datetime import datetime

def is_valid_date(string):
    try:
        datetime.strptime(string, '%Y-%m-%d')
        return True
    except ValueError:
        # parsing failed, not a valid date in the expected format
        return False
```

and use this instead of the `.startswith()` test:

```
... if is_valid_date(p)
... if is_valid_date(d[-10:])
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a validation function and use that when walk through you list like this for example:

```
import datetime

directories = [
    '2015-06-18', '2015-07-20', '2015-08-05', '2015-09-01', '2015-10-10',
    '2017-11-23', '2017-11-30', '**ata_Q1/old**', '**uonic_data**']

def isValidDate(date_text):
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(date_text, '%Y-%m-%d')
    except ValueError:
        #raise ValueError("Incorrect data format, should be YYYY-MM-DD")
        return False
    return True

out = [d for d in directories if isValidDate(d)]

print out
```

Or to wrap it up in a function like in your example and adding the `isdir()-`condition as well:

```
def listDirs(directory):
    return [d for d in os.listdir(directory) if 
               isValidDate(d) and os.path.isdir(d)]
```

Comment: The OP is also filtering the names on directories; the `os.path.isdir()` part is significant.